# How to test an application compiled for arm64-v8a architecture on phone with armeabi-v7a architecture?

Tags: android, kivy, google-play

I published [an application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph) on Google Play Store. Google requires to compile
it into arm64-v8a architecture. When compiled into armeabi-v7a architecture, it worked on my phone. One friend of mine was successful to install it and run it on arm64-v8a, at another friend
the app crashed after start, so I offered it to more people for testing and another three reported that the app crashed after start. I would like to fix the bugs, but I'm restricted to
my phone with armeabi-v7a. Is it possible to debug it with my device? [Here](https://github.com/lucidl/tedegraph-mobile) is the source code
for completeness.

Comment: **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/tdg_articles'** in line - 175

No need to ask for read permission - `request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])`

You can also remove unused imports and moved all the buttons, labels to the kv file
```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from os.path import join
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import kivy
```

Comment: @Pikro But I'm reading from external storage as well.

Comment: Now work, but you need to fix some errors in it that are not related to your question.

Comment: @Neizvestnyj OK, I see. I borrowed a device from my friend for one day. When I clicked New the application crashed. I'm now starting connecting the device and then debugging. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized what the error is, in android 11 and higher, you need to set an additional argument to view the storage (`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`), see my pull request https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/2431/commits/30a28d5a71fcca4c369d3f9ae85539515d413a6e. Edit the *AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml* file and rebuild the project.

To do this, you need to go to the project folder, `/home/<USER>/<APP>/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build/templates` - for example, and find there `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml` and you can just copy the code from my pull request or just add the desired argument as I said above

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml. It is a kivy project, so I have buildozer.spec file. And do I have the possibility to test it with my device, before I post the project to Google? Review times are about one week long, so I'd like to post the version without a bug.

Comment: And can I test it? When I only post the new release version, it will be probably reviewed longer than the duration of a bounty.

Comment: Yes, everything works in, I have the application itself uses external storage, usually checking applications takes 2 days. You can create a version for internal testing, as I know it does not pass verification and is available to testers after a few hours

Comment: OK, and should I first `buildozer android clean` of `buildozer -v android release` is enough?

Comment: Yes 1) `buildozer android clean` 2) `buildozer android debug` (check the app) 3 `buildozer android release`

Comment: I already posted the new release with only `buildozer android release` :-( I haven't seen the testing possibility there. Thanks a lot, I will try to resend it :-)

Comment: Could you please [test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph) the new version of the application if it works now?